# Set a WordPress website's language without affecting the back-end

Tags: cms

I have a WordPress website.

What I want to do is leave the back-end of the website in English, but in the meantime I want the front-end of it to be in Chinese. (So that it translates every text generated with plugins by script).

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You should raise your accepting rate to motivate people answering your new questions. To accept an answer, please click on the tick on the left of the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [WPML (WordPress Multilingual Plugin)](http://wpml.org/) and [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/) individually to see if either of them can suit your needs.

Here's also a review comparing the two: [Best WordPress Multilanguage Plugins](http://www.wpmayor.com/404/plugin-reviews/best-wordpress-multilanguage-plugins/)

Answer (score -1):

My site similar.

i install wp in english then install new theme in english then translate this by own.

you can work this way.